# Gigya migration from Objc to Swift - Facebook native login

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, gigya

I'm migrating Gigya SDK from objective-c version to swift version and I'm having difficulties with native facebook and google logins.

I'm using GigyaSwift v1.1.1 but i've checked v1.1 and 1.0 as well.

**Facebook**

everything seems to be fine except that I'm getting GigyaProfile = nil in gigya's *success*
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaCBA.png) and i'm unable to retrieve accounts details.

What i did:

- migration steps from [here](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Swift+Upgrade+Guide+Obj+C+to+Swift)
- included FacebookWrapper - which is called during logging in
- updated FBSDKCoreKit & FBSDKLoginKit to latest versions
- verified Facebook's plist configuration (FacebookAppID, FacebookDisplayName and entries in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes) -> they are fine
- verified linking AppDelegate to Facebook's SDK as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

Everything is ok when i switch back to deprecated objective-c version and i can log in without any issues so it seems there is something missing / wrong with swift version of the sdk.

Thanks for any help

Snap code

```
  public static func login(provider: GigyaProvider, viewController: UIViewController,
                             success: @escaping (_ result: GigyaAccount) -> Void,
                             failure: @escaping (LoginApiError<GigyaAccount>) -> Void) {
        guard let gigyaSocialProvider = provider.socialProvider else {
            assertionFailure("Gigya provider is nil")
            return
        }
        GigyaWrapper.shared().login(with: gigyaSocialProvider, viewController: viewController) { (response) in
            switch response {
            case .success(let data):
                success(data)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

where socialProvider is:

```
public var socialProvider: GigyaSocialProviders? {
            switch self {
            case .facebook:
                return .facebook
            case .twitter:
                return .twitter
            case .googleplus:
                return .google
            case .yahoo:
                return .yahoo
            case .apple:
                return .apple
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add snap code of login?

Comment: Hi Sagi, i've edited my initial question with code

Comment: It’s ok, where is the code had missing data?

Comment: right after success(let data): passes GigyaAccount object to callback function - ive attached image in first post

Comment: Can you make network capture (with Charles)? Also I think it’s will be better to help with an support case.

Comment: I've captured response from Gigya API and it seems ok. 

"profile" JSON object is populated with correct values however SDK's GigyaAccount's profile property is nil

Comment: do it as the official way to open cases, we need more private information for check it.